# Mark positions attacked by a queen on a chess board

Tags: interview-questions, matrix, scala, chess

**Problem** - Given a chess board and the position of only one queen piece in it, mark all the position where the queen can move with **X**.

Kindly review this Scala code and suggest improvements.

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

object ChessQueenAttack {
  val board = Array.fill(8)(Array.fill(8)('0'))
  def printBoard = {
    println
    println
    board foreach { row => println(row.mkString(" "))}
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    printBoard
    val qR = args(0).toInt
    val qC = args(1).toInt
    board(qR)(qC) = 'Q'
    printBoard

    var (r,c) = (qR, qC)

    // horizontal
    for ( i <- 0 until 8 ) {
      if (i != qC) board(qR)(i) = 'X'
      if (i != qR) board(i)(qC) = 'X'
    }

    // top left
    r = qR -1
    c = qC -1
    while (r >= 0 && c >= 0) {
      board(r)(c) ='X'
      r -= 1
      c -= 1
    }
    // top right
    r = qR - 1
    c = qC + 1
    while (r >= 0 && c  < 8) {
      board(r)(c) = 'X'
      r -= 1
      c += 1
    }
    // bottom right
    r = qR + 1
    c = qC + 1
    while (r < 8 && c < 8 ) {
      board(r)(c) = 'X'
      r += 1
      c += 1
    }
    // bottom left
    r = qR + 1
    c = qC - 1
    while (r<8 && c>=0) {
      board(r)(c) = 'X'
      r += 1
      c -= 1
    }
    printBoard
  }
}
```

Output -

```
scalac ChessQueenAttack.scala
scala ChessQueenAttack 3 3

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 Q 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


X 0 0 X 0 0 X 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 0
0 0 X X X 0 0 0
X X X Q X X X X
0 0 X X X 0 0 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 0
X 0 0 X 0 0 X 0
0 0 0 X 0 0 0 X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is very procedural, and more like how a C program would be written.  I don't consider it to be idiomatic Scala.  You should decompose the problem into functions, such as `isQueen` and `isAttacked` in my solution below.

There should be very little code left over in `main`.  As a shortcut, then, you can just plop the main code directly into the `ChessQueenAttack` by making it extend [`App`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/App.html).

```
object ChessQueenAttack extends App {
  def isQueen(r: Int, c: Int): Boolean = { (r, c) == queenPos }

  def isAttacked(r: Int, c: Int): Boolean = {
    (r == queenPos._1) ||                       // Same row as queen
    (c == queenPos._2) ||                       // Same column as queen
    (r + c == queenPos._1 + queenPos._2) ||     // On / diagonal
    (r - c == queenPos._1 - queenPos._2)        // On \ diagonal
  }

  def board: String = {
    (0 until 8).map { r =>
      (0 until 8).map { c =>
        if (isQueen(r, c))    "Q" else
        if (isAttacked(r, c)) "X" else
                              "0"
      }.mkString(" ")
    }.mkString("\n")
  }

  val queenPos = (args(0).toInt, args(1).toInt)
  println(board)
}
```